# Unknown exception(just-in- time debugger exception) in ListView drag and drop in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

The Below code is for reordering the items of listview using drag and drop functionality.
The Below code is almost similar to my actual project code except for the name property in the Entity class is of type RelativePanel, I am getting some unknown exception exactly at `get;` in the name property while dropping the items at the different place it was before.
How to solve this unknown exception(just-in- time debugger exception).

In MainPage.xaml.

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate" x:DataType="local:Entity">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding name}"></ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>

       <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListViewStyle">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="CanDragItems" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="CanReorderItems" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />

        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="xlgrid">

    </Grid>
```

In MainPage.cs

```
namespace draganddrop1
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public string name 
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        }
        public Entity(string name1)
        {
            name = name1;
        }
    }
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
        ListView listView;
        public MainPage()
        {
            

            this.InitializeComponent();

            Entities = new ObservableCollection<Entity>();
            populate();
            var itemsPanelTemplateXaml =
            $@"<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                          xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>";
            this.
            listView = new ListView {  Style = (Style)this.Resources["ListViewStyle"], ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["dataTemplate"] };

            listView.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(itemsPanelTemplateXaml);

            listView.ItemsSource = Entities;
            xlgrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }
        private void populate()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Entities.Add(new Entity("Sheet" + i.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reprodue your problem with above code, can you share more detail about your exception?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT the above code is fine, in my actual project there is problem, and in that  project name is of type relative panel, while doing drag and drop i listened to the ```ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged``` event handler, internally observable collection is doing reordering items thought, but at exactly after ```get;``` in name property a just in time debugger is raising, for reference i added image also.

Comment: Do you mean the exception occurs when call item name property get method ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yes, after the item is dropped.

Comment: I tried get the fist item name property with  `var name =  Entities[0].name;`, It works well in my side.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT it works fine by doing that, in my case after items dropped, listview is requesting for name exactly at this point exception is raising, do you thing listview is failing to display that item again

Comment: Can you provide code sample that could reporduce this problem, I will test base on that.

Comment: And if you have deleted the item please check if the items collection has upated.